# How to catch all exception in netty

Tags: java, exception, netty

As far as I know netty handle exceptions by override method exceptionCaught(). But what I want is a Handler that can handler all exceptions in or out. So, the pipeline should be like :

InboundExceptionHandler - inboundHandler1 - inboundHandler2 - outboundHandler1 - outboundHandler2 - OutboundExceptionHandler

That means I should place 2 exception Handler in my pipeline separated in head and tail. But I think it looks ugly. any better idea?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could just have a single inbound and outbound exception handler at the top/tail of your pipeline. If you want to catch all exceptions you could do something like this (I'm assuming this is Netty 4.0):

```
import io.netty.channel.*;

import java.net.SocketAddress;

public class ExceptionHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {
    
    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        // Uncaught exceptions from inbound handlers will propagate up to this handler 
    }

    @Override
    public void connect(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, SocketAddress remoteAddress, SocketAddress localAddress, ChannelPromise promise) {
        ctx.connect(remoteAddress, localAddress, promise.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                    // Handle connect exception here...
                    Throwable failureCause = future.cause();
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) {
        ctx.write(msg, promise.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                    // Handle write exception here...
                    Throwable failureCause = future.cause();
                }
            }
        }));
    }
    
    // ... override more outbound methods to handle their exceptions as well
}
```

Any exceptions that are thrown by inbound handlers will propagate "up" the pipeline and invoke this handler's `exceptionCaught()` method, assuming a handler below does not consume them.

For outbound operations like `write()` and `connect()`, you need to add a `ChannelFutureListener` to catch their exceptions. **The `exceptionCaught()` method is only invoked for exceptions from inbound events like `channelRead()`, `channelActive()` etc.**

With this handler at the "top" of the pipeline we can catch exceptions from all outbound handlers below. Say one of your outbound handlers is doing some encoding and this fails with an exception, this will be handled by our channel future listener that we added to the `write()` operation's promise.

If this exception handler was installed at the "bottom"/head of the pipeline like you initially suggested, then it would not see exceptions from handlers above it, because its `write()` method would never be invoked if the write failed in a previous handler. That's why this handler must be at the top.

To hopefully avoid confusion about top/bottom of the pipeline, here is how I would configure your example pipeline:

```
pipeline.addLast(outboundHandler2)        // bottom
        .addLast(outboundHandler1)
        .addLast(inboundHandler2)
        .addLast(inboundHandler1)
        .addLast(new ExceptionHandler()); // top
```

Comment: this cannot be used with voidPromise on write or in a way that minimizes unnecessary object creation. can you elaborate more on a optimized version

Comment: If you're using voidPromise for writes then you can't call addListener(), but any outbound write exceptions will propagate up to exceptionCaught(), so they can still be handled there. On 4.1 you can call promise.isVoid() to handle either case.

To minimize object creation, the ChannelFutureListener anonymous classes I used above could be declared as instance members so they are only created once per handler.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for this answer. I understand the inbound part, but am confused about the outbound part. Suppose there is an incoming message traveling through the pipeline. `inboundHandler1` receives the message and then responds by calling `ctx.write()`. Since `ExceptionHandler` never touches this message, how will its `write()` method be called to set up the promise callback? I think I must be missing something...

Comment: You're correct, if `ctx.write()` is called from another handler while processing an inbound message, `ExceptionHandler` will not know about it. You have a few options:  
  
- Create a ChannelPromise (`ctx.newPromise()`) and add your own listener to it, to handle exceptions in the current ChannelHandler
- Use `ctx.write(message, ctx.voidPromise())` - if it's safe to use void promises - then any write exceptions will propagate up to `ExceptionHandler`'s `exceptionCaught` method.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612403/catch-all-exception-handling-for-outbound-channelhandler

Comment: your "top" is another man's "bottom" (makes sense visually, although a pipeline is usually seen laying horizontally). I wish we would stick with the normal Netty terms of tail and head: less ambiguity :)

Comment: Your outbound exception handler cannot catch all exceptions. It will only be notified if all (outbound) handlers above it passes the promise on. I have written several tests to document this behaviour here: https://github.com/fatso83/test-driven-learning/commit/332cea2d07fc5ca47ebd568eaa8ae14f12113ef5

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is to customize the ChannelInitializer You can even add more logic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).